# For what "sleep" in recipes PiCamera?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, iot, picamera

In most part recipes for PiCamera it is `time.sleep()` before `camera.capture` ([official tutorial](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html)). Here it is only comment: *"# Camera warm-up time"*.

1. But how exactly it warms? For what?
2. Do I need make warm-up if I use `camera.capture` in a cycle? Or it is enough only one time, in first iteration?
3. How I should choose a count of seconds to warm-up?

Comment: It's probably to allow the auto-exposure and auto-whitebalance to stabilise. Not really a programming question and would probably fare better on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This is just to allow the first few frames from the camera to filter through since there is often poor quality as the stream is established. The camera also has to start up and often has poor framerate for the first second or two. Similar question asked on Raspberry Pi forums [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=92372). So yes, you need it for a single picture but no, you shouldn't need it for a cycle (unless you're losing and restarting the stream in every cycle). 2 seconds should work for your purposes; if results are poor you can increase as necessary.